# SDK Manager is missing older Android System images for emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-sdk-tools

I've just did fresh installs of the ADT bundle (20130522) and the Android Studio.  (because my eclipse install got screwed up again, but that's another story.)

In either version, when I launch the SDK Manager, I don't have any system images for 2.2, only an x86 image for 2.3.3, and no images for 3.0, 3.1, and 3.2.

I couldn't find any official word as to why they've been removed.  Is there now a better way to test on those platforms rather than by using the emulator images?

Comment: Well, the best way to test a android app is always on a device, emulator has it's limitations, tho, if you just downloaded the android studio, the option to install those images should be on your sdk manager.exe for sure, download link if needed: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: Yeah, I thought they would all show up sdkmanager.exe.  But I only see ARM images for Android 4.0 and above, not for anything else.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Check the "Obsolete" checkbox, towards the bottom of your SDK Manager window, and you should see them.

More specifically, up until Android 4.0 (or thereabouts), the ARM emulator image was not broken out into a separate download, and so you get that from the base "SDK Platform" download.

> Why would people expect the ARM image to be part of the SDK platform for <4.0, when it is broken out separately for 4.0+

Well, for those of us graybeards who have been developing for Android for a while, it's second nature... :-)

More seriously, I suspect they did not want to attempt to repackage the older releases. Bear in mind that the only available platform for Android was ARM up until about 2.3, and so having a separate ARM image download would have seemed odd back in the beginning.

Comment: Checking "Obsolete" only adds a bunch of API levels - 2.3.1 (API 9), 2.0.1 (API 6), 2.0 (API 5), and 1.1 (API 2).  But the ARM EABI v7a System Images are still not available for any of the API levels I mentioned earlier, nor the ones that get added by checking the Obsolete checkbox.  I only see ARM emulator images for Android 4.0 and above.

Comment: @Kevin: That's because there were no separate downloads for ARM emulator images for those older versions. The ARM emulator images are in the "SDK Platform" downloads (plus Google APIs-enhanced ARM images in the "Google APIs" downloads).

Comment: Umm.. wow.  I tried it by downloading the 2.2 SDK platform and it now shows up as an available target for the emulator.  This is insane and not even documented anywhere.  Why would people expect the ARM image to be part of the SDK platform for <4.0, when it is broken out separately for 4.0+... Can you repost your last comment as the answer so I can mark it correct?

Comment: @CommonsWare when obsolete ticked. Why API 8 is not obsolete while API 9 is obsolete?

Comment: @Halim: API Level 9 was for Android 2.3. That was quickly replaced by Android 2.3.3, which also gave us API Level 10. There are effectively zero devices running Android 2.3, 2.3.1, or 2.3.2. Hence, it is considered to be obsolete.

Comment: @CommonsWare Oic never knew that. Thanks, you're the best.