# How to create AVD targeted to API level 11 for Android

Tags: android, genymotion

I am creating an application which has minimum SDK setup to API Level 11. I am using API level 11 as target and compile SDK. I want to test if my application will work on API level 11 devices. I tried to get system image for API Level 11 using Android SDK manager but could not find it.
I also tried Genymotion but could not find there also. 
How can I get API level 11 system image? 
Or is there any other way I can be sure if my application will work on API 11 (Virtual machines)?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26040616/android-cannot-find-arm-images-for-api-11-12-13

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17308874/sdk-manager-is-missing-older-android-system-images-for-emulator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not care about API 11-14. If you checkout the [platform versions dashboard](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#Platform) you will see that there are no Android 3.X devices out there. Vast majority of 3.x devices have been updated to 4.x. The not updated rest are most likely inactive devices, which are not actively used.

Additionally, when targeting API 11 you target about 0% of Android users with such devices, but you do invest time in supporting it. I would really suggest to reconsider your target API and switch to API 15.